# Implement GetHashCode for IRevertibleChangeTracking class

Tags: c#, gethashcode

My current project uses Dapper to build a class based on rows from a database.

I've cut down my class to focus on the equality components of my question so please let me know if any additional code is needed:

```
public class Computer
{
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public string OperatingSystem { get; set; }
}

public class Hardware : IRevertibleChangeTracking
{
    public int Id { get; internal set; }

    private string serialNumber;
    public string SerialNumber
    {
        get => this.serialNumber;
        set => this.SetField(ref this.serialNumber, value);
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // compare against OriginalValues and store changed value in Changes
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Computer> Computers { get; }

    private Dictionary<string, object> OriginalValues { get; set; }

    // Equals override
    public override bool Equals(object value)
    {
        return this.Equals(value as Hardware);
    }

    // Equals implementation
    public bool Equals(Hardware hardware)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, hardware)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, hardware)) return true;

        return object.Equals(this.Id, hardware.Id)
           && string.Equals(this.SerialNumber, hardware.SerialNumber)
           && this.Computers.SequenceEquals(hardware.Computers);

    public static bool operator ==(Hardware hardwareA, Hardware hardwareB)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(hardwareA, hardwareB))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return !object.ReferenceEquals(null, hardwareA) && hardwareA.Equals(hardwareB);
    }       

    public static bool operator !=(Hardware hardwareA, Hardware hardwareB)
    {
        return !(hardwareA == hardwareB);
    }

    public override void AcceptChanges()
    {
        // clear changes and update original calues
    }

    public override void RejectChanges()
    {
        // clear changes and revert object state
    }
}
```

I've overridden Equals to allow my class to compare itself to other instances and to simplify Unit Tests that involve all the properties:

```
[Test]
public void CanCheckTwoHardwareAreTheSameWithEquals()
{
    var firstHardware = Database.GetHardwareById(931);
    var secondHardware = Database.GetHardwareById(931);

    // i would rather this than asserting 50 properties are equal
    Assert.IsTrue(firstAsset == secondAsset);
}
```

Overriding Equals then generated a warning within Visual Studio to also override GetHashCode. Based on my own research ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Object_GetHashCode), Googling, similar StackOverflow questions) I've come to understand that:

- If you override Equals, you should also override GetHashCode
- If an object is Equal to another object, GetHashCode should provide the same value for both objects
- GetHashCode is used by various internal collections and failing to override it correctly can cause problems when using my class with these collections
- The value from GetHashCode should not change for the lifetime of the object

As the properties of my class are all capable of changing (even ID is set to -1 and updated for new objects), instead of relying on the current values i could implement GetHashCode using the ID property and the OriginalValues dictionary as they change the least:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        // Choose large primes to avoid hashing collisions
        const int HashBase = (int)2166136261;
        const int HashMultiplier = 16777619;

        var hash = HashBase;
        hash = (hash * HashMultiplier) ^ (!object.ReferenceEquals(null, this.Id) ? this.Id.GetHashCode() : 0);
        hash = (hash * HashMultiplier) ^ (!object.ReferenceEquals(null, this.OriginalValues["SerialNumber"]) ? this.OriginalValues["SerialNumber"].GetHashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

However this will only work until someone calls the `AcceptChanges()` method on my class and the OriginalValues are changed (Thus producing a different value for `GetHashCode()`).

I've also seen a few answers here that simply `return 0` as the implementation of `GetHashCode()`

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This would return a value that is always the same, no matter how many times the properties on my class are changed.

## **Questions**

1. Is `return 0` a valid implementation of `GetHashCode` for mutable objects whose properties are expected to change?
2. Are there any downsides to be aware of for this implementation? (less performance for dictionary lookups?)

Comment: "GetHashCode is used by various internal collections and failing to override it can cause problems when using my class with these collections" - is not correct. It should read "...failing to override it **correctly**..."

Comment: Overriding `Equals` **does not** override `==`. You have to do both. And `!=` also for it to be correct.

Comment: Returning `0` for `GetHashCode` will kill the performance of your objects in any indexed collection. You don't want to do that.

Comment: Would `this.Id == -1 ? 0 : this.Id.GetHashCode()` be a better implementation than simply returning 0? The id only gets updated for new objects, i only just realized Id is not updated for existing objects.

Comment: No, not really. If the hash code ever changes then the object is broken. If you want to use `Equals`/`GetHashCode` then you must follow the rules.

Comment: Do you know that you can override `==` without overriding `Equals`/`GetHashCode`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Changing the behavior of `==` to be something different from `Equals` is *really* poor design, and will greatly confuse anyone using it.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, I agree, but the OP has mutable objects which is worse for implementing `GetHashCode`. Overriding `==` is a better, but not good, option.

Comment: @Enigmativity If you're unwilling to change the object's equality identity for a mutable object, then just *don't change it's identity* and use an external equality comparer.  If you're willing to change the identity of a mutable object, and simply trust users to not mutate objects that are the key of a hash based collection, then you should be changing *all* of the object's equality identity.  Changing just some of it is worse than either option.

Comment: @Servy - I like the option of the external equality comparer. That's a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the creation code from my class to a factory class as the factory is already responsible for creating instances of my class based on rows that already exist.

Doing so means the Id property on my class never changes after creation, this allows me to create a unique hash code with

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: XORing the hash value to a constant isn't helping anything, it's only ever removing information, or at best, doing nothing.

Comment: You might be right, i was simply copying code from other answers that used XOR for multiple properties. Would you recommend `return this.Id.GetHashCode()` as an update to the above code?

Comment: It's a better version of this solution, whether or not either are a suitable solution to the problem is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `Equals` only for testing, do not modify your class.

I prefer to use [`FluentAssertions.BeEquivalentTo`](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/) method. It compares objects by properties.

```
firstAsset.Should().BeEquivalentTo(secondAsset);
```

Som your code in class will stay clean.

Comment: I'll be using `Equals` for other purposes as well but thanks for linking me to FluentAssertions, it looks like a cool library.